# In TypeScript, how do I stop a generic type parameter from getting `unknown`-ed when it is used cyclically?

Tags: typescript

I have a function called `createDeferredObject` which works like so:

```
const box = createDeferredObject({
  contents: (box) => [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42],
  description: (box) => `This box contains ${box.contents.length} number(s).`,
});
```

I want it to be generic, allowing the creation of an object with any
keys and any values. And I want it to be able to infer the shape of the
resulting object based on the return values of the resolvers. For example, in
the example above, it would ideally infer the type of `box` (including the one
passed into the `description` resolver) as `{ contents: number[], description: string }`.

Here's how it would *ideally* be typed:

```
declare function createDeferredObject<TShape extends object>(
  init: DeferredObjectInit<TShape>
): TShape;

type DeferredObjectInit<TShape extends object> = {
  [K in keyof TShape]: (self: TShape) => TShape[K];
};
```

The goal here is to be able to infer the type of `TShape` based on the given
`DeferredObjectInit<TShape>`. Unfortunately, using the type signature above,
TypeScript does not always correctly infer `TShape`. In some cases it does, but as soon as a *potential* circular reference is created it bails out to `unknown`. The example given above is one such case.

Is there a way to statically type `createDeferredObject` such that it is able to
infer `TShape` when used in ways like the example above?

> **More Detail:** I have posted a Gist containing an **example implementation**, **further examples**, a **deep-dive** showing exactly what scenarios do and do not cause TypeScript to bail out, and a list of **failed attempts** to resolve the problem: https://gist.github.com/skfreddo/6658acd6a17dfeb6e56b75a284790169

Comment: What do you think about using a builder like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/deferrable-stqkj) to build up your `init` object?  At each stage you only build on previously defined properties, so nothing is circular.  If this works for you I'll write it up; otherwise I'm not sure what to say...

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't what I'm looking for. It's the _parallel_ inference between the fields (as opposed to the _serial_ inference in your example) that I'm trying to crack. Thanks for taking the time to put together a sandbox though!

Comment: I have a strong feeling that the answer is going to be "this is not possible with TypeScript's current inference algorithm".  Something like [microsoft/TypeScript#30134](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30134) might be needed instead.

Comment: I'm confused since your example code goes into much detail about breakage of what's essentially a serial object: `description` depends on `contents` which depends on nothing. The only circular example is `Person`, and that works just fine because it's in a contextual place where `TShape` has to be a `Person`; and if it didn't get inferred, you could always just *specify* it by `createDeferredObject<Person>(...)`. If you already have declared an interface for the shape, you can use it to skip the generic type inference. Do you have motivating type shapes that are circular and undeclared?